# Firebase Cloud Firestore error + Vue + Vuex (firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I figured out that something looks wrong with docChanges, it's a function but when I write `docChanges().doc.data().userId` comes this error `store.js?3bf3:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined`

::**UPDATE**

I would like to log in/ sign up but i get this error right now
Everything works almost fine but the `this.$router.push('/dashboard')` in the login function not. WHY?

Store.js

```
state: {
  currentUser: null,
  userProfile: {},
  posts: [],
  hiddenPosts: []
},
actions: {
    clearData({ commit }) {
        commit('setCurrentUser', null)
        commit('setUserProfile', {})
        commit('setPosts', null)
    },
    fetchUserProfile({ commit, state }) {
        fb.usersCollection.doc(state.currentUser.uid).get().then(res => {
            commit('setUserProfile', res.data())
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
},
mutations: {
    setCurrentUser(state, val) {
        state.currentUser = val
    },
    setUserProfile(state, val) {
        state.userProfile = val
    },
    setPosts(state, val) {
        if (val) {
            state.posts = val
        } else {
            state.posts = []
        }
    },
    setHiddenPosts(state, val) {
        if (val) {
            if (!state.hiddenPosts.some(x => x.id === val.id)) {
                state.hiddenPosts.unshift(val)
            }
        } else {
            state.hiddenPosts = []
        }
    }
}
```

**Error code of Login**

[image: Error code of Login]
Login.vue component

```
             <form v-if="showLoginForm" @submit.prevent>
                <h1>Welcome Back</h1>

                <label for="email1">Email</label>
                <input v-model.trim="loginForm.email" type="text" 
                 placeholder="you@email.com" id="email1" />

                <label for="password1">Password</label>
                <input v-model.trim="loginForm.password" type="password" 
                  placeholder="******" id="password1" />

                <button @click="login" class="button">Log In</button>
             </form>

        data() {
           return {
              loginForm: {
                email: '',
                password: ''
              }
           }
        },
        methods: {
           login() {
            this.performingRequest = true

            fb.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginForm.email, 
              this.loginForm.password).then(user => {
                this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
                this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
                this.performingRequest = false
                this.$router.push('/dashboard')
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                this.performingRequest = false
                this.errorMsg = err.message
            })
          },
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `querySnapshot.docChanges` as if it's an array:

```
querySnapshot.docChanges.length...
querySnapshot.docChanges[0]...
```

But [`querySnapshot.docChanges`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docChanges) is a function, so you need to invoke the function first before you get an array back:

```
querySnapshot.docChanges().length...
querySnapshot.docChanges()[0]...
```

Comment: I spent a long time trying to figure out that I needed the `[0]` after the method. Thanks!